# Sorting price along with pagination

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have total 97 pages for all the pages I have to sort the price and after sorting price for current page need to click on Next same need to do till Next button invisible, for that I have written script but I am getting wrong output **if price increasing Rs9.00 to Rs10.00 or Rs99.00 to Rs100.00** or something like this.
 Please review below script and help me to solve it

```
public class SortingItems extends WebDriverCommonLib
{
Select select;
@Test
public void pagination() throws InterruptedException

{       
Driver.driver.get("http://....");
Driver.driver.manage().window().maximize();
Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("auth_Username")).sendKeys("Test");
Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("auth_Password")).sendKeys("Test");
Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='submit-form']//i[@class='fa fa-search']")));
        Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='submit-form']//i[@class='fa fa-search']")).click();
        select = new Select(Driver.driver.findElement(By.name("product-sort")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("Price - Low to High");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement TxtBoxContent = Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/section/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[6]/a"));
        int number = Integer.parseInt(TxtBoxContent.getText()); 
        if(number>1)
        {   
        System.out.println("pagination exists: "+number);

        // click on pagination link
        for(int i=1; i<=number; i++)
        {
        try
        {
System.out.println("Page "+i);
            List<WebElement> price = Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='find_prices']"));
            List<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (WebElement e : price)
            {
                prices.add(e.getText());
            }
            List<String> sortedPrices = new ArrayList<String>(prices);
            System.out.println(sortedPrices);
            Collections.sort(sortedPrices);

            // true if the prices are sorted
            System.out.println(sortedPrices.equals(prices));

        WebElement scroll = Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='next page-numbers']"));
        scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
        Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='next page-numbers']")).click() ;
        waitForPageToLoad();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        //Driver.driver.quit();
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("pagination not exists");
        }
        }       
        }

**Output**<br/>
```

pagination exists: 97
Page 1
[4.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 6.00, 7.00]
true

Page 2
[7.00, 7.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 8.00, 9.00, 9.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00]
**false**

Page 3
[10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00]
true

.

.

.

.
Page 37
[99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00]
**false**

.

.

.

Page 84
[590.00, 590.00, 590.00, 590.00, 590.00, 595.00, 595.00, 595.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00, 600.00]
true
.
.
.

Comment: You are creating a list of string but you can create a list of float or double.  Use List<Double> sortedPrices = new ArrayList<Double>(prices);

Comment: with same code getting error  "The constructor ArrayList<Double>(List<String>) is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the collection sorting to check if list is sorted. Take the variable to store the value of last entry on page. Compare the variable with the value of current entry on page. If the current entry on page is more than or equal to last entry you are good otherwise the list is not sorted.